# Set Default MySQL Socket in PHP, pdo_mysql.default_socket PHP 5.3

Tags: mysql, centos, php

I'm having an issue setting the default PDO socket location for MySQL, without doing it through the initialisation of the PDO class into a variable. I've tried altering the mysql.default_socket variable. But no joy with that. The only way that works currently is through the class DSN instantiation.

php.ini Contents:

```
[PHP]
engine = On
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = Off
short_open_tag = On
asp_tags = Off
precision    =  14
y2k_compliance = On
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func=
serialize_precision = 100
allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off
safe_mode = Off
safe_mode_gid = Off
safe_mode_include_dir =
safe_mode_exec_dir =
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
disable_functions =
disable_classes =
expose_php = Off
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
variables_order = "EGPCS"
register_globals = Off
register_long_arrays = Off
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 8M
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
doc_root =
user_dir =
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"
enable_dl = On
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 500M
allow_url_fopen = On
default_socket_timeout = 60

[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables  = Off

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off

[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port = 3306
mysql.default_socket = /home/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_host = 127.0.0.1
mysql.default_user = conner
mysql.default_password = danica4eva
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket = /home/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_host = 127.0.0.1
mysqli.default_user = conner
mysqli.default_pw = danica4eva
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[mSQL]
msql.allow_persistent = On
msql.max_persistent = -1
msql.max_links = -1

[PostgresSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0

[Sybase]
sybase.allow_persistent = On
sybase.max_persistent = -1
sybase.max_links = -1
sybase.min_error_severity = 10
sybase.min_message_severity = 10
sybase.compatability_mode = Off

[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent = On
sybct.max_persistent = -1
sybct.max_links = -1
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
sybct.min_client_severity = 10

[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0

[Informix]
ifx.default_host =
ifx.default_user =
ifx.default_password =
ifx.allow_persistent = On
ifx.max_persistent = -1
ifx.max_links = -1
ifx.textasvarchar = 0
ifx.byteasvarchar = 0
ifx.charasvarchar = 0
ifx.blobinfile = 0.
ifx.nullformat = 0

[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
session.use_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor     = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = 0
session.bug_compat_warn = 1
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 1
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off

[Verisign Payflow Pro]
pfpro.defaulthost = "test-payflow.verisign.com"
pfpro.defaultport = 443
pfpro.defaulttimeout = 30

[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400

zend_extension = /etc/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
```

As you can see, I have changed the default socket settings within the php.ini file, but I still get a socket error in PDO when I try to connect to MySQL. It leads me to believe that the PDO driver is not using the settings from the php.ini. I was sure that there was some way of configuring PDO, but there was nothing within my php.ini. Should there be settings for PDO within the php.ini, or are they contained elsewhere?

Comment: `but I still get a socket error`. Do you have error message? Can you execute a small php cli example with strace?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a different ini setting for the PDO mysql driver. It is called

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket
```

Have you tried to set this ini value? Please refer to http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

The value can also being influenced during compile time using the following configure option:

```
--with-mysql-sock=/my/path/mysql.sock
```

**Update**: I've figured out that the problem is a known [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50829).

First: you can workaround the problem when using 127.0.0.1 as the db host instead of localhost. PHP will connect trough a TCP socket this way.

To change the location you'll have to compile PHP from sources with special configuration options. I was successful to change the location of the mysql socket with the following (basic) command lines :

```
 ./configure \
  --with-mysql \
  --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
  --enable-pdo \
  --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
  --with-mysql-sock=/home/mysql/mysqld.sock

 make
 make install
```

The final trick made the combination of the last both of them. `--with-mysql-sock=file` sets the location of the .sock file **but** it is just used if `--with-pdo-mysql=` is set to `mysqlnd` (mysql native driver). If this option is missing pdo would be linked against the libmysqlclient from the system. As a result of this you can also recompile libmysqlclient (with modified socket path) and leave php untouched.

Note: This is just the basic configuration to make PHP working with PDO. You'll need additional configuration options if you need additional extensions (like json, xml, whatever). You'll find the configuration that your Linux Distribution has used to compile PHP if you execute the (original distribution) version this way: `php -i`.

Comment: Yes, I tried adding that, but it was just ignored as well. Really annoying. I see on the documentation that you provided there, that you can use the ./configure script to add it, where is this script located? I've been looking for it, but I can't seem to find it. I'm running CentOS 6.4.

Comment: ./configure is a script that is used when compiling PHP from sources. Is this an option for you?

Comment: I didn't realise this was on compile of PHP. I would prefer it, if it just worked from the php.ini. What would I put for the 'pdo_mysql.default_socket' option. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Ok will try to prepare an example. Just for interest, why do you need this? :) The problem sounds a little bit 'exotic' (but interesting) to me.  Which OS do you use?

Comment: I use CentOS 6. It's a new installation using one of OVH's ready to use SolusVM templates. So I had to change some settings as I have my partitions set so that my main partition is mounted as the home directory. This is where I store my MySQL data and such and the socket is situated in there as well, the exact location is /home/mysql/mysql.sock, so I need to point PHP to that socket off of the bat, as I'm using a billing system on the server and it does not allow me to change the DSN for the system. So I need PDO to automatically go to /home/mysql/mysql.sock for the socket.

Comment: One another question. Can you post the output from phpinfo (or php -i) to some pastebin? (If security allows so). Would potentially save other questions

Comment: Thank you! during my investigations I stumpled upon this bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50829 Maybe interesting to you...

Comment: Yeh, I seen that this was a common issue, but I can't seem to find any fixes for it :/ it's becoming very frustrating...

Comment: Update: Can reproduce the problem using the debian squeeze version of PHP (5.3.3) . Ubuntu's version hasn't the problem

Comment: The example in the answer is generic. It will work on CentOS too. Can't you just use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? Then the socket will not being used at all.

Comment: Where do I change this setting? EDIT: In fact, it's already set to 127.0.0.1 anyway, and it still requires a sock. So I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: When I test it using 127.0.0.1 it will not use the socket.. Try to compile from sources as I described. In addition you'll find many help on PHP compilation on SO and the web.

Comment: I do apologise, you were right, you don't have to use the socket if you use the localhost local IP address. The billing system I use had it set to localhost. The only annoying thing with this is that I have to change it on all my scripts.