# Configure php PDO default socket

Tags: php, postgresql, apache

Is it possible to configure php, PDO, or possibly apache, to specify the default Unix socket location? I am using php PDO to access Postgresql locally using socket. Postgresql is:

`listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"`

Specifying the socket location in the PDO connection string does not work. It is straight from the php manual.

`$dsn = "pgsql:host=/tmp;port=5432;dbname=$db";`

[PDO_PGSQL DSN examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php)

**This is explained and solved in a previous question.**

[PHP PDO Unix socket to Postgresql fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77565944/php-pdo-unix-socket-to-postgresql-fails)

One of the suggested solutions works.

`$dsn = "pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=$db";`

I prefer this solution, also suggested.

`$dsn = "pgsql:dbname=$db";`

That fails because it is looking for the socket in */var/run/postgresql/*:

```
$ curl http://localhost/lamp/index.php
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
```

The closest I could find is to modify the php.ini file, but it does not apply to postgresql

[Set Default MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205826/set-default-mysql-socket-in-php-pdo-mysql-default-socket-php-5-3)

**Test Code Snippet (php 8.1.12)**

```
                $dsn = "pgsql:dbname=$db";

                // make a database connection
                return new PDO(
                        $dsn,
                        $user,
                        $password,
                        [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]
                );
```

Comment: Just to flip things around, can you tell PostgreSQL to put the socket in the location that PHP expects? I know it seems like a hack, but I'm seeing a good number of people struggling with this problem, and they all seem to be attacking it in different ways.

Comment: Yes. That was suggested in the answer to my original question as well. I have started down that path but /var/run is not accessible to the postgres user. I'm sure I can sudo around that, bit would prefer to see if it is at all possible to configure.

Comment: Depending on the response to this I may also update php. I'm on php 4.1.12.

Comment: `I'm on php 4.1.12`, are you sure? The latest patch for 4.1 was over 20 years ago, February 2002. And I can't find 4.1.12 anyway. You might consider an upgrade to version 8.3 or at least to version 8.2

Comment: That PHP version can't be correct. The short array syntax `[]` you are using for the fourth parameter to PDO wasn't introduced until PHP 5.4. Maybe you mean 8.1.12 or 7.1.12? And actually, I think PDO didn't exist until the 5.x timeline, although I think it lived in PECL for a bit

Comment: Thank you. PHP 8.1.12 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2022 17:30:00).

Comment: Zend Engine v4.1.12 Exposing my deep knowledge of php.